# MVC Checkbox not checked when value is true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a grid of records that contain a check box.  The check box indicates whether the transaction has been acknowledged or not. For testing purposes, I added a display text next to the check box and the text indicates that the boolean is true.  However, the check box is not checked.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.TransactionList.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="hidden"> @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ProviderTransactionId)</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].Acknowledged)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].Acknowledged)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.TransactionList[i].Acknowledged)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].FromUicTxt)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].FromUicTxt)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ToUicTxt)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ToUicTxt)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].PrimaryUicTxt)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].PrimaryUicTxt)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].Action)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].Action)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].InitiatedDateString)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].InitiatedDateString)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ProviderFirst) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ProviderLast)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ProviderFirst) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ProviderLast)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SSN)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SSN)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SendersFirst) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SendersLast)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SendersFirst)@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SendersLast)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SendersPhone)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].SendersPhone)
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try with clearing the ModelState.

Comment: Thanks vortex!  If you want to put it in the answer section i can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Why would you have a hidden input for the same property after the checkbox? (it will just be ignored)

Comment: That was there from earlier before I changed it to a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with clearing the ModelState. `ModelState.Clear()`. This way the CheckBox helper will get the value from your model and not from the ModelState, where might have a conflict with your property name.